# Laravel 5: eloquent-sluggable resluggify relationship data

Tags: laravel-5.1, slug

I am a newbie to Laravel and have been developing an app. I am using Laravel 5 and to get pretty URL's i am using eloquent-sluggable. 
I have 2 tables, Users and Artists and their respective models. I have relationship in Artist table. In the Artists model i have the below code.

```
      class Artist extends Model implements SluggableInterface 
    {

        use SluggableTrait;

        /**
         * The database table used by the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'artists';

        /**
         * @var array
         */
        protected $sluggable = [
            'build_from' => 'users.name',
            'save_to'    => 'slug',
        ];

 public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

I am trying to use tinker to update the existing data in database to slug. I have created a new field in artists table called slug. When i run the below command:

```
$artists = \App\Artist::all()
foreach ($artists as $artist) { $artist->name->resluggify()->save(); }
```

i get below error:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Fatal error: Call to a member function resluggify() on string
```

How can i update the existing data in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a look at the documentation for `cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable` as I'm assuming this is the package you're using.

`name` in this case is just a string so you wouldn't be able to call any methods from it which is what you're code is trying to do.

Looking at it, the method `resluggify()` it is just a helper function for

`sluggify(true)` - `true` is just telling it to sluggify the model even if the model has already been "slugged"

So the following should work:

`$artist->resluggify()->save()`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. It was my mistake, i had to update the model to `implement SluggableInterface` and then use the Trait.

```
use SluggableTrait;
```

This resolved the issue and i was able to resluggify.